# Enable session with wsHttpBinding in wcf

Tags: c#, wcf, wshttpbinding

I've written this code:

interface:

```
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    string Welcome(string fullName);

    [OperationContract]
    string Goodbye();

    [OperationContract]
    string GetSessionID();

    [OperationContract]
    CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);
}
```

service:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    private string UserFullName { get; set; }

    public string GetSessionID()
    {
        var sessionId = OperationContext.Current.SessionId;
        return sessionId.ToString();
    }

    public string Welcome(string fullName) 
    { 
        UserFullName = fullName ?? "Guest"; return string.Format("Welcome back, {0}!", UserFullName); 
    }    

    public string Goodbye() 
    {
        return string.Format("Come back soon, {0}!", UserFullName ?? "Guest"); 
    }

    public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
    {
        if (composite == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
        }
        if (composite.BoolValue)
        {
            composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
        }
        return composite;
    }
}
```

webconfig:
[image]

Why is UserFullName always null?

Comment: Please don't use the version-specific tags like "c#-4.0 c#-3.0" unless your question is specific to those versions.

Answer (score 1):

Change *InstanceContextMode.**PerCall*** to **PerSession**.

In your example an instance of the service is created every call.

Comment: OK, to have a session you either need to use **message security** or turn on **reliable session**. Another solution is to create a custom binding with this - <httpsTransport authenticationScheme="Anonymous" requireClientCertificate="true"/>

Comment: reliable session is turn on but does not work.what do you mean about custom binding?

Comment: Did you try to turn on Message Security? For custom binding Look @ this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396961/why-wcf-instancecontextmode-persession-is-not-working-over-https

Comment: OK is it true that wsHttpBinding does not support sessions?

Comment: It should. Did you try message security?